# How to apply java.security file loaded into Oracle database

Tags: java, database, oracle, security

To add a security provider to the embedded Oracle database 12.2 Java I loaded java.security file into the database using this instruction:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/database-contents-Oracle-JVM-security.html#GUID-F8F1FB30-8FFC-4866-BE9D-43FB97FCF4AA

The provider still does not appear in the list of providers. How make it visible? I can add files from the filesystem using

```
dbms_java.set_property ( 'java.security.properties' , '=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/javavm/lib/security/java.security.alt' )
```

and provider appears but

```
dbms_java.set_property ( 'java.security.properties' , '=lib/security/java.security.alt' )
```

do not work, it makes the provider list empty.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself. In documentation chapter describing classpath extentions
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/classpath-extensions-user-classes-metadata.html#GUID-C948182D-D9C7-45DB-9B7A-648BBCA47F6E
template for URL is jserver:/CPcSCHEMAc. For java.security.alt it will be

```
dbms_java.set_property ( 'java.security.properties' , '=jserver:/resource/schema/SYS/lib/security/java.security.alt' )
```